# Maven jar dependency not found at runtime by OSGi environment

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle, tycho

I'm building an Eclipse product that requires some external dependencies, which are not bundled as Eclipse plugins.
For example `javax.json-1.1.4.jar`.

I'm usign a target platform file, with Maven dependency added. This is the relevant part of the .target file:

```
<location includeDependencyScope="compile" includeSource="true" missingManifest="generate" type="Maven">
            <dependencies>
                ......
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.4</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </location>
```

The resulting bundle is included from the plugin that uses this Json implementation: this is the MANIFEST of the plugin

```
Require-Bundle: org.glassfish.javax.json;bundle-version="1.1.4"
```

The plugin compiles and run normally. The problem happens at runtime, when the Json implementation is loaded:

```
2022-03-11 09:44:18,166 ERROR [main]: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
2022-03-11 09:44:18,168 ERROR [main]: 
javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:99)
    at javax.json.Json.createReader(Json.java:225)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.utils.MotorDataHandler.parseMotorJsonFile(MotorDataHandler.java:64)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.utils.DBHandler.initMotorsDB(DBHandler.java:209)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.utils.DBHandler.getMotors(DBHandler.java:116)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.impl.FieldBusDevice.getMotors(FieldBusDevice.java:1323)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.impl.FieldBusDevice.createFromSiriusString(FieldBusDevice.java:1257)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.impl.HwConfiguratorFactoryImpl.createFieldBusDeviceFromString(HwConfiguratorFactoryImpl.java:252)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.impl.HwConfiguratorFactoryImpl.createFromString(HwConfiguratorFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHelperImpl.createFromString(XMLHelperImpl.java:1615)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHelperImpl.setValue(XMLHelperImpl.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setFeatureValue(XMLHandler.java:2710)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setAttribValue(XMLHandler.java:2769)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.SAXXMIHandler.handleObjectAttribs(SAXXMIHandler.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectFromFactory(XMLHandler.java:2247)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl cannot be found by javax.json-api_1.1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:96)
    at javax.json.Json.createReader(Json.java:225)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.utils.MotorDataHandler.parseMotorJsonFile(MotorDataHandler.java:64)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.utils.DBHandler.initMotorsDB(DBHandler.java:209)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.utils.DBHandler.getMotors(DBHandler.java:116)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.impl.FieldBusDevice.getMotors(FieldBusDevice.java:1323)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.impl.FieldBusDevice.createFromSiriusString(FieldBusDevice.java:1257)
    at com.test.mas.rcp.hwconfigurator.sirius.core.impl.HwConfiguratorFactoryImpl.createFieldBusDeviceFromString(HwConfiguratorFactoryImpl.java:252)
```

The `javax.json-1.1.4.jar` is not found at runtime by the api jar `javax.json-api_1.1.4`.

The only way I found to make it work is to add the implementation jar to the runtime classpath settings of the plugin, in the Bundle-Classpath:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/javax.json-1.1.4.jar,
```

This requires the jar in the lib folder of the plugin, while it is already included from the tartget platform. It should be enough..
Is there a configuration or something to be done to make the OSGi environment recognise the jar as a Maven dependency at runtime?
I have read about `Eclipse-BuddyPolicy` and `DynamicImport-Package` but I don't know how to used them in my case, and if they are usefull.

This https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonp/issues/96 says that it "Should be fixed with javax.json:1.1.4 and jakarta.json:1.1.5" but I don't
get how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem, thanks to the comments in this thread:

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jax-ws-api/issues/90

in particular the last one:

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jax-ws-api/issues/90#issuecomment-952793454

This is related to a veri similar problem I had with the implementation of the
`com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl` web service provider.

Including the [OSGi Resource Locator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/osgi-resource-locator/2.5.0-b42) in the bundle manifest, and the plugin with the actual implementations, make them discoverable at runtime.

This is the dependency in the target platform file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-b42</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

In the end, for the Json problem, I switched to the Eclipse Parsson implementation which works at runtime without problems.
These are the needed dependencies in the target platform:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.parsson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.parsson</groupId>
    <artifactId>parsson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```